# firebase.auth().currentUser is always null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my app I'm logging in the user with firebase `.signInWithEmailAndPassword` on the back-end node.js app but I'm trying to build user presence on the front-end. The problem is on the front-end `firebase.auth().currentUser` doesn't detect the logged in user. How do I detect the logged in user with `firebase.auth()` on the client side?

Comment: Chances are that you're calling `` before the authentication state is restored. I recommend using the first snippet from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user. If that doesn't solve the problem for you, post a [minimal, verifiable example with which anyone can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The method calls you mention now are used by millions of developers, so the problem stems from how you use them.

Comment: On the backend I'm logging in the user with this code: 
`firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    //`
While on the front end I POST to the login route above. Running the `firebase.auth().currentUser` command on the back end works fine but running `firebase.auth().currentUser`  in chrome dev tools using the firebase js sdk returns null even after the user is logged in.

Comment: Please update your question to include a standalone [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run as is, or show a reproduction of the problem on a site like jsbin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `signInWithEmailAndPassword` on a backend and have that affect the sign-in status of the user on the frontend. You're supposed to sign in the user on the frontend only, then pass user credentials to the backend as needed for verification if needed.